# .htaccess does not work on pages reached from form post

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am reaching this page from index form

index.php

```
    <form action = 'upload' method = 'post' name = 'former' id = 'former'>
```

upload.php cannot find the values from the posted forms if I perform a .htaccess name rewrite

Placing this in .htaccess makes uplaod.php unable to read the posted values:

```
         RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /upload\s [NC]
         RewriteRule . UploadStampLibanPost/ [R=301,L]
         RewriteRule ^UploadStampLibanPost/$ upload.php [L]
```

This .htaccess Lines should be removed so the form is able to read

```
         name = 'typ' value = 'value1'

          http://www.us-traders.com/
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ignore `POST` request from external redirect like this since redirect will not carry POST data to new URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /upload\s [NC]
RewriteRule . UploadStampLibanPost/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^UploadStampLibanPost/$ upload.php [L]
```

Comment: I ahd to make method -  get from index.php and added this to work: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
Does this mean I am unable to use form post when I want to implmenet changing fiel name and paramater ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. If you redirect when in POST request then POST data gets lost.

Comment: Now This is what I used, but had to make it get from index.php method = get

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /upload\s [NC]
#RewriteRule . UploadStampLibanPost/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^UploadStampLibanPost/$ upload.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /upload\s [NC] 
RewriteRule . UploadStampLibanPost/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^UploadStampLibanPost/$ upload.php [L]

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide rules there as it is difficult to understand from comments.

Answer (score 0):

POST data isn't carried through on a **301 Moved Permanently** so you'd either need to post your form directly to upload.php, or change your .htaccess to not issue a 301.

Comment: What do you mena, can you explain please

Comment: In your form you are sending the data by the method **POST** which essentially (keeping it simple) embeds the information into the connection your computer makes when you hit the submit button. It sends this data to **/upload** but then it receives a response back because of your .htaccess saying "**Hey, my URL is now at /upload.php**" so it starts a __new__ request (thus loosing the POST data) to upload.php so nothing is sent on. You need to remove change your .htaccess to something like
`RewriteRule    ^/upload?$    upload.php    [NC,L]`

Comment: I am extremely lost, this si the portion, where what should I change:


#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /upload\s [NC]

#RewriteRule . UploadStampLibanPost/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^UploadStampLibanPost/$ upload.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /upload\s [NC] 
RewriteRule . UploadStampLibanPost/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^UploadStampLibanPost/$ upload.php [L]

Comment: Is there a reason why you want your form going to `/upload` but have it redirect to `/upload.php`? Why not just change the form?

Comment: I have tried action = 'upload.php' as well, did not work, as  ageneral rule I want to hide the language the website is built of by hidinh any .php sihn that can be viewed inside the html page